Session not available in GraphQL resolver
I am trying to build an express app using graphql-http. I started off
by creating a captcha endpoint as follows. But having trouble
integrating session middleware.
        app.use(session({
            secret: 'your-secret-key', 
            resave: false,              
            saveUninitialized: true,    
            cookie: { secure: false }  
        }));
 
        let schema = buildSchema(/* GraphQL */`
          type Query {
            captcha: String
          }
        `);

        // The root provides a resolver function for each API endpoint
        let root = {
            captcha: (args, context) => {
                const captcha = svgCaptcha.create();
                context.req.session.captcha = captcha.text;
                return captcha.data;
            }
        }

        app.all(
            "/graphql",
            createHandler({
                schema: schema,
                rootValue: root,
                context: req => ({ req })
            })
        )
    }


I am expecting session to be available in the captcha resolver.
My query is this:
query { captcha }

But I get this error:
"Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'captcha')"


What is in req.session ? Is that being set?

Nope. That is the problem.
